# Oracle Forms shows a blank page while running in web browser

Tags: oracle, forms, installation, oracle10g, report

I have a problem with  oracle  10g forms. It compiled and when it is running in Internet Explorer it is showing a blank page after Successfully Installation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Once you launch Forms URL, it will launch Java in the background and your application should show up.

Two think you have to do:

- make sure java is installed on your computer
- make sure Internet Explorer allows java to be launched

Now after you did that, activate the java console and logs:

- type `javaws` in dos command line
- go to *advanced* and check:

[image]

If you see nothing in java logs, then you must go to your server logs to see if anything interesting shows up. This part depends on your installation. Now Internet again is your friend, e.g. [this](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/32405/)...

Comment: @QaiserAwan, happy to read it was helpful. Do not hesitate to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).